# Julia: Match any type belonging to a Union

Tags: julia

I have a `Union{Type1, Type2, Type3}`, which matches all values whose type is one of those types. But how do I match the types themselves?

```
MyU = Union{Float64, Int, Array}
a::MyU = 3.5 # works
a = 5 # works
a = [1, 2, 3] # works
# but of course
a = Float64 # nope
a = Int # nope
a = Array # nope
```

With normal types this is usually achieved via `Type{MyType}`, whose only value is `MyType`. But `Type{MyU}` matches only `MyU`, and not the types it contains. How do I match those?

I can of course just use `DataType`, but this has two issues:

1. It matches any type, not only those I want.
2. It doesn't match UnionAll types, like `Array`.

My current workaround is `Union{DataType,UnionAll}`, but it's an ugly hack that is additionally bound to crash and burn if I include another `Union` or some other non-concrete type into `MyU`.

My other solution is to make a second, parallel Union like so:

```
MyU = Union{Float64, Int, Array}
MyUT = Union{Type{Float64}, Type{Int}, Type{Array}}
```

It does work and is more strict, but it's also ugly and introduces large possibility of human error with manually keeping those in sync.

Comment: I'd say your "parallel Union" is the way to go. You could circumvent the problem of keeping them in sync by automatically constructing `MyUT` from `MyU` using a macro for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider something like this to avoid macros (which can be tricky):

```
gettypes(u::Union) = [u.a; gettypes(u.b)]
gettypes(u) = [u]
typewrap(u) = Union{[Type{v} for v in gettypes(u)]...}
```

and then:

```
julia> MyU = Union{Float64, Int, Array}
Union{Float64, Int64, Array}

julia> MyUT = typewrap(MyU)
Union{Type{Array}, Type{Float64}, Type{Int64}}
```

**EDIT**

As an additional note, you can define `gettypes` as one liner like this:

```
gettypes(u) = u isa Union ? [u.a; gettypes(u.b)] : [u]
```

**EDIT 2**

Or yet simpler without an intermediate array:

```
typewrap(u) = u isa Union ? Union{Type{u.a}, typewrap(u.b)} : Type{u}
```